# SPRESENSEでFreeRTOSが使用できない

Tags: c++, spresense, arduino

現在、SPRESENSEのArduino互換でFreeRTOSライブラリを用いてマルチスレッド化しようと考えております。

しかしながら、検証を行ったところ以下のようなエラーが出てしまい、利用できません。
サンプルのプログラムを実行しようとした際も同じようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
main:3:10: fatal error: avr/io.h: No such file or directory
3 | #include <avr/io.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
```

SPRESENSEでFreeRTOSライブラリ利用はできないのでしょうか。
こちらのエラー原因ご存じの方がおりましたら、解決策をお教えいただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらのサイトにも同様の投稿がありました。問題解決の参考になるかもしれません。 https://qiita.com/tarotaromake/questions/7edaee8e17dd5ca0f6c7 また、もしこの投稿が[マルチポスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/%e3%83%9e%e3%83%ab%e3%83%81%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b-%e4%bd%95%e3%81%8b%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b)であった場合は、質問文へマルチポスト先の URL を追記することで、詳細な回答が得られやすくなります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そもそもSPRESENSEのArduinoはNuttXというRTOS上で動いています。
というわけでマルチスレッド化したい場合はNuttXの機能を使うのが手っ取り早いでしょう。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます！
SDK版のみNuttXだと思い込んでおりました。
NuttXの操作はArduino互換版でも可能ということでしょうか。

Comment: 実のところ私は実機を持っていないのですが[Spresense Arduino 環境における task\_create 関数のプライオリティ指定について - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59999/spresense-arduino-%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-task-create-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E3%83%97%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)など、Arduino上からtaskを利用している例が観測できました

Comment: 参考の資料ありがとうございます。そもそも、FreeRTOSは対応不可だったようです。
NuttxではPthreadがうまく回りそうでした。大変参考になりました。ありがとうございます。